# Ajax passing Null to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

I tried to create Incident chart which can change the periods (Last 7 days/Last 30 days/Last 90 days). 
However, I tried to pass it via ajax data to controller, but I got NULL value there.
 How can I solve it? Below is my code.

Blade:

```
<div id="periods" class="btn-group float-right">
                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle p-0" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Periods
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="periods-select">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last 7 days</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last 30 days</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last 90 days</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

JS file

```
  $("#periods").on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();

    var text = $(this).text();
    var periodTime = text.replace(/\D/g, "") - 1;

    $.ajax({
      method: "get",
      url: "/",
      data: {
        id: periodTime
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
    
  });
```

Controller

```
   public function index(Request $request) 
   {

  
            $length = $request->id;
            dd($length); <== NULL value.
.....

        return view('dashboard.homepage', compact('chartDataByDay'))->render();
   }
```

webp

```
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.homepage');
```

Comment: Could you just check adding a console log into your js file, whether you are getting a value for periodTime

Comment: I already tested and it shows value. (6 / 29 /89)

Comment: Did you check  $request->all() shows the id value in your controller?

Comment: Yes. It shows [ ].

Comment: Try Route::get('/{id} ', 'DashboardContro... and inside the controller, index function parameter is id like function index($id) { dd($id)}

Comment: dd($id) shows the number that I put in http://127.0.0.1:8000/6

Comment: Back to my code. I put this code in controller.   if( $request->ajax() ) { $length = $request->id;  dd('hihi'); } else { $length = 30; } It 's not show 'hihi' when I change the dropdown menu.

Comment: Add datatype:json to your ajax request like $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'theRoute',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#main-wrapper').html(data);
            }, 
            error: function(){
                console.log('AJAX load did not work');
            }
        });

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: Sorry. forget quotes

Comment: Ajax success. But It 's still not workingg

Comment: Then use this in your controller $request->query('id'); this should work.

Comment: Let me know whether it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should get the parameter from query string using query method.

```
$request->query('id');
```

Comment: It 's still not work. Howver, I gotta go. Tomorrow I will test it again. Thank you veryy much.

Comment: It works now. However, it seems the dropdown menu is not working after success.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: It' ok now. I changed success function to    success:function(data){  $('#c-core').append("<div class='ajax'>"+data+"</div>");   $('#c-core .ajax').remove();    $('#c-core').append(data);  }, Thank you very much.

Comment: I voted you but it show "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."